# How to use multiple XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, for-loop

I need to get 8 JSON from 8 different URL. I stored the query string that I have to change in an Array and I loop through it with a for loop. Here is my code:

```
var index = ["ESL_SC2", "OgamingSC2", "cretetion", "freecodecamp", "storbeck", "habathcx", "RobotCaleb", "noobs2ninjas"];

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

for (var i = 0; i < index.length; i++) {

    var url = "https://wind-bow.glitch.me/twitch-api/channels/" + index[i];

    request.open("GET", url);
    request.onload = function() {
        var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
        console.log(data);
    }
    request.send();
}
```

So far I just want to display each JSON on the console. I don't get any error but I can display only the last JSON with the last index item (noobs2ninjas).

Could anybody explain me why? how do I get the all JSON that I need?

Thanks

Comment: Just when you think you're getting the hang of XMLHR this is waiting to hit you :-/

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> Could anybody explain me why? how do I get the all JSON that I need?

In order to send a second request you need to wait for the first to finish. Hence, if you are interested to get the responses in the array order you can loop on each array element and only when you get the response you can loop on the remaining elements:

```js
var index = ["ESL_SC2", "OgamingSC2", "cretetion", "freecodecamp", "storbeck", "habathcx", "RobotCaleb", "noobs2ninjas"];
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
(function loop(i, length) {
    if (i>= length) {
        return;
    }
    var url = "https://wind-bow.glitch.me/twitch-api/channels/" + index[i];

    request.open("GET", url);
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(request.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && request.status === 200) {
            var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
            console.log('-->' + i + ' id: ' + data._id);
            loop(i + 1, length);
        }
    }
    request.send();
})(0, index.length);
```

Instead, if you want to execute all the request completely asynchronous (in a concurrent way), the **request** variable must be declared and scoped inside the loop. One **request** for each array element. You have some possibilities like:

- using [let](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let)
- declaring a callback
- using [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression)
- using array [.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) instead of a for loop

```js
var index = ["ESL_SC2", "OgamingSC2", "cretetion", "freecodecamp", "storbeck", "habathcx", "RobotCaleb", "noobs2ninjas"];


for (var i = 0; i < index.length; i++) {

    var url = "https://wind-bow.glitch.me/twitch-api/channels/" + index[i];

    let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("GET", url);
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(request.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && request.status === 200) {
            var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
            console.log('-->' + data._id);
        }
    }
    request.send();
}
```

As per @Wavesailor comment, in order to make a math computation at the end of calls:

```js
var index = ["ESL_SC2", "OgamingSC2", "cretetion", "freecodecamp", "storbeck", "habathcx", "RobotCaleb", "noobs2ninjas"];
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
(function loop(i, length, resultArr) {
    if (i>= length) {
        console.log('Finished: ---->' + JSON.stringify(resultArr));
        return;
    }
    var url = "https://wind-bow.glitch.me/twitch-api/channels/" + index[i];

    request.open("GET", url);
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(request.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && request.status === 200) {
            var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
            console.log('-->' + i + ' id: ' + data._id);
            resultArr.push(data._id);
            loop(i + 1, length, resultArr);
        }
    }
    request.send();
})(0, index.length, []);
```

Comment: What's the difference in using "onreadystatechange" compared to "onload"?

Comment: @Dema You need to wait the operation completes correctly while [load](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/load): The load event is fired when a resource and its dependent resources have finished loading.

Comment: I don't get yet why the loop function is able to keep the order in which the array elements are set (seems to me like is doing exactly what a for loop would do) but it does what you said so I guess I just need to think about it more thoroughly. Thanks for giving me the two options

Comment: @gaetanoM Great examples but could I ask you to explain the first one in more detail - I got lost with the manner in which you define the function `loop` and how it is called. Additionally how would I create a function that would use the results of the Ajax calls to calculate something which will be displayed i.e. can only calculate once I have all the values from the Ajax calls.

Comment: @gaetanoM - IIFE - yes thanks that's it -  I'll read up on it. With regards to the math operation: I'm guessing I should store the results in an array but I am finding it hard to figure out how to only let the math operation begin once all the Ajax calls are complete. i.e. ((result from Ajax call 1 + result from Ajax call 2)  * result from Ajax call 3 * result from Ajax call 4.

Comment: @Wavesailor Added a last snippet to the answer. I hope it helps. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

The problem is that you declare

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
```

outside of the `for` loop. So you instance only one request.

You have to include it **inside** the for loop.

Also, don't forget that **ajax** is executed **asynchronous** so you will get the results in a **random** order.

The value of `i` variable must be declared using `let` keyword in order to declare a **block scope** local variable.

`let` allows you to declare variables that are limited in **scope** to the **block**.

`let` is always used as a solution for [closures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work).

Also, you can use an `array` where you can store the `XMLHttpRequest`.

```js
var index = ["ESL_SC2", "OgamingSC2", "cretetion", "freecodecamp", "storbeck", "habathcx", "RobotCaleb", "noobs2ninjas"];
requests=new Array(index.length);
for (let i = 0; i < index.length; i++) {
    var url = "https://wind-bow.glitch.me/twitch-api/channels/" + index[i];
    requests[i] = new XMLHttpRequest();
    requests[i].open("GET", url);
    requests[i].onload = function() {
        var data = JSON.parse(requests[i].responseText);
        console.log(data);
    }
    requests[i].send();
}
```

Comment: I tried but I get this error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at XMLHttpRequest.request.onload

Comment: try not to parse your response. It looks like one of your responses is not properly formatted JSON

Comment: @NikitaMalyschkin, I updated my answer with the final solution.

Comment: Thanks. Now I understand

Comment: I altered this recently to handle two requests to NOAA and it worked immediately. Thanks. Would help to include some way of handling the request data in your code IMO.

Answer (score 6):

You may also prefer to use the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) in the place of `XMLHttpRequest`. Then all you have to do is to utilize a few `Promise.all()` functions.

```js
var index = ["ESL_SC2", "OgamingSC2", "cretetion", "freecodecamp", "storbeck", "habathcx", "RobotCaleb", "noobs2ninjas"],
    url   = "https://wind-bow.glitch.me/twitch-api/channels/",
    proms = index.map(d => fetch(url+d));

Promise.all(proms)
       .then(ps => Promise.all(ps.map(p => p.json()))) // p.json() also returns a promise
       .then(js => js.forEach((j,i) => (console.log(`RESPONSE FOR: ${index[i]}:`), console.log(j))));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
max-height: 100% !important;
}
```